# Нужно вывести слова на заданную букву. При отладке появляется ошибка: "нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу"

Tags: c++

При отладке происходит ошибка: Вызвано исключение по адресу

```
0x6E8FD4EC (ucrtbased.dll) в Lab 24.exe: 0xC0000005:
нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x00500000.
```

Код

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Введите текст");
    char str[256], tmp;
    gets_s(str);
    int n = strlen(str), count;
    printf("Введите букву:");
    char t;
    scanf_s("%s", &t);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == t)
        {
            if (str[i - 1] == 32 && i != 0 || i == 0)
            {
                count = 0;
                while (str[i] != 32 && i < n)
                {
                    i++;
                    count++;
                }
                if (str[i - 1] == ',')
                    for (int j = i - count; str[j] != ','; j++)
                        printf("%s", str[j]);
                printf(" ");

            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Точно - при компилировании?

Comment: Когда отладку запускаешь

Comment: А это уже не компиляция, а работа. Кстати, написали бы, раз отлаживали, в какой строчке проблема...

Comment: Почему вы пользуетесь функцией `scanf_s` не удосужившись даже разобраться, что она делает и как ее правильно вызывать?

Comment: Скажите еще, что такое в вашем понимании (и программе) **слово**?

Answer (score 0):

Если ошибка не при компиляции, а при работе - то если читает `char`, то надо использовать спецификатор `%c`, а не `%s`.

```
char t;
scanf_s("%s", &t);
```

=>

```
char t;
scanf_s("%c", &t, 1);
```

Это только о слете! О том, будет ли ваша программа работать - разговор отдельный... Например, при выводе вы делаете то же самое - используете не тот спецификатор:

```
printf("%s", str[j]);
```

Comment: Да действительно в этом. Но лучше не стало. Я ввожу любую букву и оно просто не выводит и я не знаю в чем может быть проблема. Я поменял спецификаторы уже везде на %с

Comment: @lkie: Еще раз: почему вы пользуетесь функцией `scanf_s` не удосужившись даже элементарно разобраться, что она делает и как ее правильно вызывать? И формат `%s`, и формат `%c` в `scanf_s` требует указания размера принимающего буфера. Где ваше указание размера буфера?

Answer (score 0):

Функция `scanf_s` требует указания размера принимающего буфера как для формата `%s`, так и для форматов `%c` и `%[]`. Вы же почему-то не указываете размер буфера (почему?), по каковой причине ваш вызов `scanf_s` некорректен.

Если вы собираетесь читать один символ, то это

```
char t;
scanf_s("%c", &t, 1u);
```